# Python package versions of package installed by pip and by installer

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, package

- I'm a Windows user of Python. I used `pip` to install packages, and I have about a dozen of packages in Python global package repo. However, there were packages I **could not** install using `pip`, e.g: numpy, scipy, matplotlib, lxml. To my understanding, installing package by `pip` requires compiling, and installation failed because they could not be compiled for some reason.
- For the workaround, I installed using the installer (.exe) files of the packages. They work all fine, and appear in Control Panel list of installed program as such:

[image]

- Recently, I can install/update all package smoothly with pip, which *I think* because I installed Cython and/or have MinGW GNU compiler in PATH. However, seems that `pip` **keeps its own version** of installed packages: e.g. `pip list` still shows matplotlib-1.3.1, numpy-1.7.2 etc.
- I test by: `pip install -U lxml`, lxml in `pip list` becomes 3.4.1, but the 3.3.3 in the Control Panel is still there. Looks like I'm having 2 version of lxml.
- Another test: matplotlib-1.4.2 (latest) was installed by exe installer. But under pip's view it's still 1.3.x. Now calling `pip install -U matplotlib`, this invokes the latest matplotlib, numpy and some other packages being downloaded, compiled and installed. Only after that, `pip list` returns the latest version number.

So why this strange behavior? (However `import` call always result in the later version installed). Should I uninstall all the packages by exe installer and reinstall them by `pip` for "consistency"?

In the `pip` way, although installation finished successfully, the compiler threw a bunch of warnings for some packages.

Comment: Warnings tend to happen for many packages. If you're able to build the packages yourself, then it does seem better to uninstall the .exe installed ones and use the same installation approach for all packages from now one.

Comment: Definitely remove the EXE packages before replacing them with locally built versions. Alternatively you can continue using the EXE packages for the system Python and build/install wheel (.whl) packages in virtual environments.